# new (new Hoge())はどんな効果をもたらしますか？

Tags: php

コードリーディングをしていたところ
↓のようなソースコードを発見しました。
（プライベートリポジトリのため具体なソースコードの掲載は控えます）

```
$ins = new Hoge();
・・・・・・
$ins2 = new $ins();
```

これはどのような意味ですか？
今まで見たことがない書き方だった為、気になっております。
検索にも出てこないので具体的な影響が理解できておれずにいます。

ご回答の程よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 3):

タイトルに記載の`new (new Hoge())`は正確ではありません。
[こちら](https://php.net/manual/ja/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new)の`new`の項目にも記載されていますが、インスタンスの元になったオブジェクト（例の場合は`Hoge`オブジェクト）の**別の**インスタンスを作成します。下記を実行すると分かると思いますが、新しいインスタンスと元になったインスタンスには依存関係はありません。PHP5.3.0以上で使える命令となります。

```
<?php
class Hoge {
    public $val = 0;
    public function sample(){ echo 'sample'.nl2br(PHP_EOL); }
}

$obj1 = new Hoge();
$obj1->val = 1;
$obj2 = new $obj1();
echo $obj1->val.nl2br(PHP_EOL);// 1
echo $obj2->val.nl2br(PHP_EOL);// 0
$obj2->sample();

var_dump($obj1!==$obj2);// True
```

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございます

Comment: 普通にnewするのとのは何が違うんですか？もし違いがなければ普通のnewに書き換えてしまいたいですが、この文法のメリットがわかりません･･･

Comment: @user35191 違いは特にありませんが、メンテナンスの時に例えばネームスペースが重複していて同じオブジェクト名があった場合、オブジェクト名を1箇所変更するだけで済みますね。あっちこっちで`Hoge`,`Hoge`書いていると全部直さないといけないので、そういったメリットはあるかと。